# iOS UI automation how to kill the process when test is hang

Tags: javascript, bash, instruments, xcode-instruments

im Using instrument and javascript to do my automation.

any idea how to kill instrument when the test hang?
i was planning to put a time out in my script so if the time out exceeded it will kill the instrument..

any bash cmd to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like `pkill instruments` ?
Unfortunately I don't have a mac to test it.

If you don't have a running process named *instruments* you can use the `top` command to find the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

You can push and pop a timeout on your tests and if it fails, throw an exception. The script will stop running and if you're using the command line, everything will stop. Now, if you really want to kill the Instruments process running at the end of the failure; just put everything on a simple shell script with **killall "iPhone Simulator"** at the end.